# How to - Tomcat JNDI resource for a spreadsheet/any simple file?

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi, spreadsheet

I would like to configure a spreadsheet or some simple file as a resource for my web application through Tomcat. Something like JDBC data source. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the path to some resource, you can use the VM argument: something like this...

```
-D<property_name>=<path_to_resource>
```

Comment: Not just path - I need the file as a resource for the web application. I want to use it like a database.

Comment: It depends on the situation then...If the contents doesn't change often, you could cache the file in some in-memory database (like HSQLDB) and create a connection pool to it.  If it changes very frequently and you have to use the file, check out apache commons pool framework (http://commons.apache.org/pool/).  You can create few inputStream objects to your file and fill up the pool with those streams.  Then checkout/check-in those references like any other pool.

Comment: Thanks so much! The file changes very frequently. The pool framework that you have pointed is interesting. I've been searching for some examples that discuss working code but couldn't find any. Could you please suggest few? MTIA!

Comment: Here's a decent article on it: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2005/jw-0124-pool.html

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for Tomcat Resources. You just have to write yourself an LdapObjectFactory, very easy, and refer to it in a Resource entry in context.xml.